# How to use "compound order by" in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Suppose there is a SQL statement:

```
select * from A order by cola
```

In sqlalchemy, we can use this code:

```
session.query(A).order_by(asc(cola))
```

Now I want to use a "compound order by" in SQL:

```
select * from A order by cola, colb
```

Then how will I translate it into sqlalchemy code? Can I use:

```
session.query(A).order_by(asc(cola, colb))
```

Probably I can't do it like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find I can do this:

```
session.query(A).order_by('cola, colb')
```

Then this problem will be solved.

Comment: Also you can do: `qry = qry.order_by(cola).order_by(colb)`. The order in which you add `order_by(...)` statements is significant.

Comment: just select your answer as correct answer so this question will be complete its workflow.